# Constructors in Java with implicit return type

Tags: java, constructor

I know pretty well about all the things regarding Constructors in Java, which I pen down below so as to ensure :

It can be tedious to initialise all the variables in a class each time an instance is created.

It would be simpler to have all the setup done at the time the object is first created.

Because the requirement for initialisation is so common, Java allows objects to initialise themselves when they are created. 
This automatic initialisation is performed through the use of a constructor.

The constructor is automatically c/d immediately after the object is created, before the new operator completes.
They don’t have a return type, not even void.

Reading Herbert Schildt The Complete Reference, I came across this paragraph.

> The implicit return type of a class' constructor is the class type itself. It is the constructor's job to initialise the internal state of an object so that the code creating an instance will have a fully initialised, usable object immediately.

I see myself really confused with the term 'implicit return type' even when knowing well constructors have no return type, not even void.

Can someone?

Comment: Not sure what your question, a constructor is kind like other methods, except that it returns an instance of the class, that's why you don't have to do `MyClass MyClass(String param) {}` you can omit the first MyClass because all constructors do the same thing

Comment: This means having no setters and all the fields of the object have to be present in order to create that object of that class. This is a great way to ensure that all the fields of the object are present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a confusing piece of text, basically. There's no concept of a return type for a constructor, as you say - you can think of them as being a *bit* like a method with a return type of the same type, but:

- Java (annoyingly) lets you declare that sort of method directly, and it's *not* a constructor:

  ```
  public class Test() {
      // This is a spectacularly unhelpful method name. 
      public Test Test() {
          return new Test();
      } 
  }
  ```
- The behaviour isn't really the same, particularly when it comes to chained constructors, where all the constructors work on the same object.
- You never return anything.

I would try to avoid thinking of constructors as methods - there are too many ways in which they're special.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari I am amazed you didnt know who he is!!

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: you should consider to accept an answer if it was helpfull. Also check your other question if you could accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If there were any implicit return value, we would see it in the bytecode. Here is an example of object initialization taken from [this article about bytecode](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-bytecode-fundamentals-using-objects-and-calling-methods/):

```
Job job = new JobImpl();
```

```
4:  aload_0
5:  new #2; //class JobImpl
8:  dup
9:  invokespecial   #3; //Method JobImpl."<init>":()V
12: putfield    #4; //Field job:LJob;
15: return
```

`5` creates the new instance. Both `5` and `8` put it on the stack so it can be popped twice, by the constructor invocation `9` and saving the reference `12`. There is no value returned from the constructor that gets saved.

Neither is there any `areturn` in the constructor bytecode that would return a value:

```
public JobImpl();
  Code:
    0:  aload_0
    1:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4:  return
```

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari probably `javap -c JobImpl`

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the constructor as a method instead of a constructor, it essentially takes the arguments and returns a new instance of the object. This is exactly what happens in Java 8 where you can do `ClassName::new` to get a factory method.

This functionality is obscured from the user and there is an implicit call to `super()` in constructors, which means that they are not quite the same as regular functions/methods. From the perspective of the user, they have no return type, but you can think of them as having a return type.